# Reduce Time Complexity: Finding Minimum Difference between Elements in List

Tags: python, arrays, list

My goal is to find the minimum difference between any two elements in a list. I wrote the following code, but I wonder if there is a more efficient way in terms of Time Complexity.

```py
    def minimumAbsoluteDifference(arr):
        arr.sort()
        min_diff = abs(arr[0] - arr[1])
        for i in range(len(arr)):
            for j in range(i+1, len(arr)):
                if abs(arr[i] - arr[j]) < min_diff:
                    min_diff = abs(arr[i] - arr[j])
                else:
                    continue
        return min_dif
```

Comment: think about which pairs of numbers are actual candidates to be the answer.  For example, of the pairs (4, 6), (4, 10), and (4, 12), are these all potential pairs that could produce the minimum absolute difference?  Why or why not?

Comment: @KevinWang I included `arr = list(set(arr))` and am trying to remove the second for loop for j by replacing j with i+1, but am getting stuck due to index out of bound

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, if you look carefully, you will see that you don't need to use two loops once you sort the list. You can directly do in the following way -

```
def minimumAbsoluteDifference(arr):
    arr.sort()
    min_diff = 10**10       #Initilising to an huge value
    for i in range(len(arr)-1):
        if arr[i+1] - arr[i] < min_diff: 
            min_diff = arr[i+1] - arr[i] 
    return min_dif
```

---

### How Does it Work ? -

- Once you sort your list, the **potential candidate for minimum absolute difference** are only the **adjacent elements**.
- Once you move away from adjacent element, the absolute difference is bound to increase
- For eg, consider the sorted list to be `lst = [2,3,5,8,15]`. We start comparing 2 and 3. Once we compare them, we don't have to compare 2 and 5 since the difference between them will always be larger than adjacent elements. Similarly, we only compare `3 and 5` and not `3 and 8` or any further elements with 3.

---

So this modified solution will work in `O(nLogn)` time complexity which is faster than using 2 loops `O(n^2)`.

Hope this helps !

Comment: thank you for your help, it worked. I just have one question, won't this leave out the last pair?

Comment: I looped till `len(arr)-1)` because we are comparing `arr[i+1]` and `arr[i]`. The last comparison will be `arr[len(arr)-2]` and `arr[len(arr)-1]`. So no pairs will miss out

Comment: okay got it. Thanks!

Comment: instead of a huge value initialization you can take the diff from the first 2 elements and iterate over the others

Answer (score 1):

Once you have a sorted array, you don't need to scan all pairs: obviously, the difference between element i and element i+1 will be smaller or equal to the difference between the (i,i+2) elements.
A quicker approach will be to check the difference between every two adjacent elements:

```py
def minimumAbsoluteDifference(arr):
   # assumption: there is more then one element in array
   arr.sort()
   min_diff = arr[1] - arr[0]
   for i in range(1, len(arr)):
      curr_diff = arr[i] - arr[i-1]
      min_diff = min(min_diff, curr_diff)
   return min_diff
```

Iterates through the array which is `O(n)`. Every time this code choose the minimum between current difference and minimum difference found so far.
`arr.sort` take `O(nlogn)`, so total time complexity is `O(nlogn)`. Your original code required `O(n^2)`

Answer (score 1):

The shortest way to do that:

```
def minimumAbsoluteDifference(arr):
    arr.sort()
    min_diff = float('inf')                               # initiating with infinity value
    for i in range(2, len(arr)):                          # start from the second element
        min_diff = min(min_diff, abs(arr[i] - arr[i-1]))  # use the built-in minimum python method 
    return min_dif
```